# Using Collect Values Tool with Union in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I would like to feed a list of feature classes (only one polygon per feature class, but up to 150 feature classes) into the Union tool in ModelBuilder by using a Feature Class Iterator and the Collect Values Tool.

Unfortunately, it does not work since "Collect Values" only works with Merge, Append, etc.

Does anyone know a workaround or another way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by writing a python script that inserts a list of feature classes into the union tool.

To use this method:

1. In Catalog create a toolbox
2. Create a Script tool
3. Make the input parameter Features Class that accepts multiple values
4. Copy the code below to a text document
5. Save the text document and change the extension from .txt to .py
6. Reference the .py file within the Script tool
7. Run the Script tool

   ```
   import arcpy

   myList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).split(";")

   unionResult = "C:\\temp\\union.shp" # make sure you have this directory C:\\temp
   arcpy.Union_analysis(myList, unionResult, "ALL", "", "GAPS")
   ```