# Algorithm to implement for batch processing in ArcMAP modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have a directory with about 10 polygon shapefiles. I need ArcMAP to take all these shapefiles and union them all into one layer using the model builder. I know I need to use some sort of iterator, however the basic one does not successfully union them all, but rather only the last one. What am I doing wrong here? Here is the model:

[image]

Comment: I think that you don´t need to use modelbuilder, just with put inside of the union all the layers together you will have the same product. If you need to reproject or do other process maybe it will helps you

Comment: Pau, this is only one small part of a huge algorithm I am constructing. I only show this small part to keep things simple. I know I don't need to go through the model builder to union a couple of vectors. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user32882 sorry, i thought that it was the complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work if you use a [Collect Values tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Collect_Values/004000000005000000/) between `ZPS 83 polygone` and the Union tool. In the first example on the [Help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000001m000000):

> The output of Collect Values, Collected Values, is a multivalue of rasters and is input to the Mosaic To New Raster tool.

This will therefore pull all the iterated features into one "input" for the Union tool to work on.

Comment: Erica thanks for your help, this is true however when I try to use the output of the collected values tool as the input of my Union, union does not see this as a valid input...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/djokOSv.jpg?1

Comment: @user32882 Try manually drawing the connection from `Collected Values` to `Union` with the [Connect Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w00000028000000) -- otherwise, not sure :\

Comment: looks like the Arc designers overlooked this one... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53620/collect-values-tool-and-union-in-model-builder

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that :) On the plus side, that answer has a script that should do the trick for you!